# Creating a function to make folders of photos black and white in R

Tags: r, image, function

Hey so I'm having an issue trying to make a function to basically streamline binarizing a folder of images to black and white.

So this  works:

```
library("EBImage")
orig = readImage("C:\\Users\\Max Aleman\\Desktop\\Cotonesterlder - Copy\\68-85-a.PNG")
gray = orig
colorMode(gray) = Grayscale
display(gray)
image(gray) #Works
```

This is great because it's perfect and gives me what I want but it doesn't save the photo into another folder and I'd have to do this per image file and I have over 600 images that need to be made black and white.

And then this function works:

```
library(raster)
for (i in 1:length(Images))
  {
  outRaster = raster(Images[i])
  writeRaster(outRaster, filename=paste(directory, '/binary/', Images[i], sep=""), format='GTiff', overwrite=TRUE)
  #write into subdirectory, keep original name
}
```

where it's grabbing the images directly from the folder and then doing nothing with them:

```
 directory <- "C:\\Users\\Max Aleman\\Desktop\\Cotonesterlder - Copy"
    setwd(directory)

    ## create vector containing all image filenames
    Images <- dir(directory, pattern="\\.PNG$") #edit the pattern (case sensitive!) if you want to exclude/include images

    ## create the subdirectory
    dir.create(file.path(directory, 'binary'))
```

So basically I have a bunch of white files. I Was wondering if there was a way in which I could basically just read through every image in a file, make it black and white (with the first code that works), and then have it saved to another file?

Comment: You're quite right, you should make a function (what you have isn't a function, its just some lines of code). Write something like `make_black_and_white <- function (path) {}` and fill in the parentheses with whatever you do to `path` to turn it into black and white. Then you can just call `lapply(Images, make_black_and_white)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So this might sounds really dumb but is there any way you can explain that a little more? 
what do you mean by path? Currently I have `make_black_and_white <- function (path) {
  orig = readImage(path)
  gray = orig
  colorMode(gray) = Grayscale
}`

But I'm not sure it's doing anything? I'm not sure how to call it up the images to see if it worked and I'm still not sure how to get these images that are black and white to save into a folder?

Comment: `path` is just the name of the argument to your function. It could be anything. For finding out if your code is working, `debug` is your friend, and couldn't you just call `image(gray)` inside the function to check it?